# Hibernate: Mapping multiple classes to same table with different primary keys

Tags: hibernate

As outlined in the heading, I am seeing problems whereby I am attempting to map two different classes to the same table.
Each class has a different primary key; one has a primary key equal to that on the physical table, the other uses a composite of 2 different fields.

The reason I am attempting this is because we recently switched the primary key on the table, and we would like to be able to support the legacy classes and the new classes.

Can some confirm if what I am doing is not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you declare same table, with two different classes, it will work but you should give a serious thought for that idea as it could create many problems in the future.

Since, **the primary keys are changed in the table, inserting data to the table using the old bean is not going to work any more**. so, essentially there is not much use with your old class.

What I would suggest is to change your old class's `id` mapping to reflect the new changes you have made in the table. The difficult part is to manage the change in the database, since you  have do that, the corresponding Java change must be simpler, give it a try.